# The Last part of titanic data modelling has refused to give the desired result and I dont know why. Error is from the last three lines of the code

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, dataset, data-science

I am working on the titanic dataset and I needed to make predictions of survival rate. Everything seems to be working good, the issue is on the last three lines of the code (the third line of the code at the bottom = df_KNN["PassengerId"] = test2["PassengerId"]). It's giving me a NameError, and I dont understand why. I have checked over and over but can seem to figure out where the problem lies precisely.

````
    titanic_data = pd.read_csv('titanic_dataset/train.csv')
    titanic_test = pd.read_csv('titanic_dataset/test.csv')
 
    titanic_data.head()
 
    titanic_test.head()
 
    survived = titanic_data[titanic_data["Survived"]==1] 
   ["Sex"].value_counts()
    dead = titanic_data[titanic_data["Survived"]==0] 
   ["Sex"].value_counts()
    df_sex = pd.DataFrame([survived,dead])
    df_sex.index = ["Survived","Dead"]
    df_sex.plot(kind="bar",stacked = True, figsize = (8,4))
 
    # We can see from the chart above that females have a higher chances 
    of survival than male. 
 
    combined_data = [titanic_data, titanic_test]
 
    for data in combined_data:
        data["Prefix"] = data["Name"].str.extract(' ([A-Za-z]+)\.', 
    expand = False)
 
    titanic_data["Prefix"].value_counts()
 
    # We map our data accordingly. 
    Prefix_mapping = 
 
 
 
 {"Mr":0,"Miss":1,"Mrs":2,"Master":0,"Dr":3,"Rev":3,"Major":3,"Mlle":1,"Co 
 
 
 l":3,"Capt":3,"Sir":3,"Ms":1,"Lady":3,"Mme":2,"Countess":3,"Jonkheer":3," 
   Don":3}
 
 
    for data in combined_data:
         data["Prefix"] = data["Prefix"].map(Prefix_mapping)
 
    titanic_data.head()
 
    titanic_test.head()
 
titanic_test["Prefix"] = titanic_test["Prefix"].fillna(3)
titanic_test.describe()
 
for data in combined_data:
    data.drop(columns = "Name",inplace=True)
 
titanic_data.head()
 
titanic_test.head()
 
# Cabin Vs Survival 
 
import seaborn as sns
 
sns.heatmap(titanic_data.isnull(), yticklabels = False, cbar = False)
 
titanic_data["Cabin"].isnull().value_counts()
 
 
titanic_data["Cabin"] = titanic_data["Cabin"].fillna(0)
for i in range(891):
    if(titanic_data.at[i,"Cabin"]!=0):
        titanic_data.at[i,"Cabin"]=1
titanic_data.head()
 
sns.countplot(x = "Survived", hue = "Cabin", data= titanic_data)
 
survived = titanic_data[titanic_data["Survived"]==1]["Cabin"].value_counts()
dead = titanic_data[titanic_data["Survived"]==0]["Cabin"].value_counts()
df_cabin = pd.DataFrame([survived,dead])
df_cabin.index = ["Survived","Dead"]
df_cabin.plot(kind="bar",stacked = True, figsize = (8,4))
 
# Too many null values in the cabin. 
# we give cabin numbers to passengers accordingly. 
# No cabin = 0 
# Have cabin = 1
 
titanic_test["Cabin"] = titanic_test["Cabin"].fillna(0)
for i in range(417):
    if(titanic_test.at[i,"Cabin"]!=0):
        titanic_test.at[i,"Cabin"]=1
 
titanic_test.head()
 
# Passenger Class and Survival Rate: 
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.countplot(x = "Survived", hue = "Pclass", data = titanic_data)
 
# From the bar above, passengers from the first class had a higher survival rate 
# Many passengers in Third Class did not survive.
# Passenger Class is an important factor while predicting the survival rate of the passengers.
 
# Age 
# data visulaization to see how age influences the survival rate of the passengers 
# Check if age has any null value 
 
sns.heatmap(titanic_data.isnull(), yticklabels = False, cbar = False)
 
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
sns.boxplot(x="Pclass",y="Age",data=titanic_data)
 
first = titanic_data["Age"][titanic_data["Pclass"]==1].mean()
second = titanic_data["Age"][titanic_data["Pclass"]==2].mean()
third = titanic_data["Age"][titanic_data["Pclass"]==3].mean()
print("Average age for First class Passenger : ", first)
print("Average age for Second class Passenger : ", second)
print("Average age for Third class Passenger : ", third)
 
for data in combined_data:
    data["Age"] = data["Age"].fillna(0)
 
for i in range(891):
    if(titanic_data.at[i,"Age"]==0):
        if(titanic_data.at[i,"Pclass"]==1):
            titanic_data.at[i,"Age"]= first
        elif(titanic_data.at[i,"Pclass"]==2):
            titanic_data.at[i,"Age"]= second
        else:
            titanic_data.at[i,"Age"]= third
for i in range(418):
    if(titanic_test.at[i,"Age"]==0):
        if(titanic_test.at[i,"Pclass"]==1):
            titanic_test.at[i,"Age"]= first
        elif(titanic_test.at[i,"Pclass"]==2):
            titanic_test.at[i,"Age"]= second
        else:
            titanic_test.at[i,"Age"]= third
 
titanic_data.describe()
 
titanic_test.describe()
 
fac = sns.FacetGrid(titanic_data, hue = "Survived", aspect = 5)
fac.map(sns.kdeplot,'Age',shade=True)
fac.set(xlim=(0, titanic_data["Age"].max()))
fac.add_legend()
 
# Looking at the age range. 
# Age range : 0 - 20 
 
fac = sns.FacetGrid(titanic_data,hue = "Survived", aspect = 5)
fac.map(sns.kdeplot,'Age',shade=True)
fac.set(xlim=(0,titanic_data["Age"].max()))
fac.add_legend()
plt.xlim(0,20)
 
# Age range : 20 - 30
 
fac = sns.FacetGrid(titanic_data,hue = "Survived", aspect = 5)
fac.map(sns.kdeplot,'Age',shade=True)
fac.set(xlim=(0,titanic_data["Age"].max()))
fac.add_legend()
plt.xlim(20,30)
 
# Age range : 30 above
 
fac = sns.FacetGrid(titanic_data,hue = "Survived", aspect = 5)
fac.map(sns.kdeplot,'Age',shade=True)
fac.set(xlim=(0,titanic_data["Age"].max()))
fac.add_legend()
plt.xlim(30,75)
 
# Observation : 
 
# age 0 - 20 are more likely to survive than to die
#  age 20 - 30 are more likely to die
# Elderly people are more likely to survive 
 
 
 
# 5. Sex and Survival Rate :
 
survived = titanic_data[titanic_data["Survived"]==1]["Sex"].value_counts()
dead = titanic_data[titanic_data["Survived"]==0]["Sex"].value_counts()
df_sex = pd.DataFrame([survived,dead])
df_sex.index = ["Survived","Dead"]
df_sex.plot(kind="bar",stacked = True, figsize = (8,4))
 
 
# Female passengers have a higher chance of survival than their male counterpart. 
 
# Male = 0 
# Female = 1 
 
 
dummy = pd.get_dummies(titanic_data["Sex"])
dummy.head()
 
titanic_data["Sex"] = dummy["female"]
titanic_data.head()
 
dummy2 = pd.get_dummies(titanic_test["Sex"])
titanic_test["Sex"] = dummy2["female"]
titanic_test.head()
 
# Embarked and Survival Rate 
 
emb_dummies = pd.get_dummies(titanic_data["Embarked"])
emb_dummies.head()
 
titanic_data["Q"] = emb_dummies["Q"]
titanic_data["S"] = emb_dummies["S"]
titanic_data.drop(columns="Embarked",inplace = True)
titanic_data.head()
 
emb_dumm = pd.get_dummies(titanic_test["Embarked"])
titanic_test["Q"] = emb_dumm["Q"]
titanic_test["S"] = emb_dumm["S"]
titanic_test.drop(columns="Embarked",inplace = True)
titanic_test.head()
 
# PassengerId and Survival Rate
 
titanic_data.drop(columns = "PassengerId", inplace = True)
titanic_test.drop(columns = "PassengerId", inplace = True)
titanic_data.head()
 
# Ticket and Survival Rate  
 
titanic_data.drop(columns = "Ticket", inplace = True)
titanic_test.drop(columns = "Ticket", inplace = True)
titanic_data.head()
 
# Fare and Survival Rate 
 
plt.figure(figsize=(5,8))
sns.boxplot(x="Survived",y="Fare",data=titanic_data)
 
# Observation: 
# The average money spent on the ticket was more for the passengers that survived.
 
titanic_data["Fare"].isnull().value_counts()
 
titanic_test["Fare"].isnull().value_counts()
 
 
# The titanic_test dataset has one null value. 
# replace this with the average fare of the people in the same passenger class
 
 
first_fare = titanic_data["Fare"][titanic_data["Pclass"]==1].mean()
second_fare = titanic_data["Fare"][titanic_data["Pclass"]==2].mean()
third_fare = titanic_data["Fare"][titanic_data["Pclass"]==3].mean()
print("Average Fare for First class Passenger : ", first_fare)
print("Average Fare for Second class Passenger : ", second_fare)
print("Average Fare for Third class Passenger : ", third_fare)
 
titanic_test["Fare"] = titanic_test["Fare"].fillna(0)
 
for i in range(418):
    if(titanic_test.at[i,"Fare"]==0):
        if(titanic_test.at[i,"Pclass"]==1):
            titanic_test.at[i,"Fare"]= first_fare
        elif(titanic_test.at[i,"Pclass"]==2):
            titanic_test.at[i,"Fare"]= second_fare
        else:
            titanic_test.at[i,"Fare"]= third_fare
 
titanic_test["Fare"].isnull().value_counts()
 
fac = sns.FacetGrid(titanic_data,hue = "Survived", aspect = 5)
fac.map(sns.kdeplot,'Fare',shade=True)
fac.set(xlim=(0,titanic_data["Fare"].max()))
fac.add_legend()
 
fac = sns.FacetGrid(titanic_data,hue = "Survived", aspect = 5)
fac.map(sns.kdeplot,'Fare',shade=True)
fac.set(xlim=(0,titanic_data["Fare"].max()))
fac.add_legend()
plt.xlim(0,100)
 
# Passengers who paid a lower fare were most likely from Second or Third class and therefore had a lesser chance of surviving.
 
 
 
titanic_data["Family"] = titanic_data["SibSp"] + titanic_data["Parch"] + 1
titanic_test["Family"] = titanic_test["SibSp"] + titanic_test["Parch"] + 1
 
for data in combined_data:
    data.drop(columns = ["SibSp","Parch"],inplace =True)
 
titanic_data.head()
 
titanic_test.head()
 
plt.figure(figsize = (12,6))
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.countplot(x = "Survived", hue = "Family", data = titanic_data)
 
# Observation 
# Those with companions had higher chances of survival than those who travelled alone. 
 
 
#   Feature Scaling and Titanic_data - Titanic_test - Split
 
# We should scale the data before making our model with any of the various algorithms. 
 
 
 
X = titanic_data[["Pclass","Sex","Age","Fare","Cabin","Prefix","Q","S","Family"]]
Y = titanic_data["Survived"]
X_TEST = titanic_test[["Pclass","Sex","Age","Fare","Cabin","Prefix","Q","S","Family"]]
 
print(X)
 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X = sc.fit_transform(X)
X_TEST =  sc.transform(X_TEST)
X
 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size = 0.2, random_state=1)
 
# MAKING OUR MODEL 
 
# K - Nearest Neighbor Algorithm
 
 
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
 
acc = []
 
for i in range(1,20):
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = i)
    knn.fit(X_train,y_train)
    yhat = knn.predict(X_test)
    acc.append(accuracy_score(y_test,yhat))
    print("For k = ",i," : ",accuracy_score(y_test,yhat))
 
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.plot(range(1,20),acc, marker = "o")
plt.xlabel("Value of k")
plt.ylabel("Accuracy Score")
plt.title("Finding the right k")
plt.xticks(range(1,20))
plt.show()
 
# From the graph above, the preferred value for k that gives us the highest accuracy is k = 9
 
 
    KNN = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 9)
    KNN.fit(X,Y)
    y_pred = KNN.predict(X_TEST)
 
    y_pred
 
df_KNN = pd.DataFrame()
df_KNN["PassengerId"] = test2["PassengerId"]
df_KNN["Survived"] = y_pred
df_KNN.head()


```


I dont know what when wrong with my code. I was trying to show accuracy of the survival rate from the titanic dataset but I got a NameError at the end of end of it all. Every part of my code is correct apart from the last three lines.
````

Comment: Would you share the error message directly? That will help us better understand what the issue is :)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I didn't find any mention of `test2` variable in your code. Maybe there should be `df_KNN["PassengerId"] = titanic_test["PassengerId"]`?

Comment: This is the error message: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [68], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 df_KNN = pd.DataFrame()
----> 2 df_KNN["PassengerId"] = test2["PassengerId"]
      3 df_KNN["Survived"] = y_pred
      4 df_KNN.head()

NameError: name 'test2' is not defined

Comment: I had changed 'test2' to 'titanic_test', and also tried 'titanic_data'.. I also got the error.